# If copy constructor is not generated, which constructor is used when initializing from an already existed object

Tags: c++, constructor

My code is as follow:

```
class X {
public:
    explicit X(int x):m_x(new int{x}) {
        cout << "------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Constuctor X(int x)"<<endl;
        cout << this << endl;

    }

    X() {
        cout << "------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Constuctor X()"<<endl;
        cout << this << endl;
    }

    ~X() {
        cout << "------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Destructor"<<endl;
        cout << this << endl;
    }

    int* m_x = nullptr;
    const int c_x = 10;
};

int main() {
  X x1;
  X x2{x1};
}
```

And the output:

```
------------------------------------
Constuctor X()
0x7ffc22667cb0
------------------------------------
Destructor
0x7ffc22667cc0
------------------------------------
Destructor
0x7ffc22667cb0
```

The question is: when I define constructor X() and X(int x), all other constructor were not generated any more, so which constructor was used when initializing object x2?

Comment: [If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor)

Comment: You are confusing your rules. The default constructor is not generated if other constructors are defined, but this rule does not apply to copy constructors or move constructors.

Comment: Side note :  having a copy constructor while you have an owning raw member pointer is not a good idea anyway. Consider updating your example to NOT have a raw member pointer.

Answer (score 8):

A default copy constructor *was* created.

If you want it to *not* be created, add:

```cpp
X(const X& x) = delete;
```

Compiling this would yield:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:34:10: error: use of deleted function ‘X::X(const X&)’
   X x2{x1};
          ^
```

Consider that it's a bad idea for a class with a raw pointer member to use the default copy constructor as that will only copy the *pointer* and not the data it points to. Suggested reading: [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

In your example, if you delete `x1.m_x`, `x2.m_x` is left invalid.

```
class X {
public:
    explicit X(int x):m_x(new int{x}) {
        cout << "Constuctor X(int x)"<<endl;
    }

    X() {
        cout << "Constuctor X()"<<endl;
    }

    ~X() {
        cout << "Destructor"<<endl;
    }

    int* m_x = nullptr;
    const int c_x = 10;
};

int main() {
  X x1(23);
  X x2{x1};

  delete x1.m_x;

  cout << *x.m_x << endl;
}
```

Running this on my machine:

```
% ./a.out                
Constuctor X(int x)
-2011512784
Destructor
Destructor
```

A custom copy constructor for this class would look something like the following, where the instance now owns its own data for `m_x` to point to.

```
    X(const X& x) : m_x(new int{*x.m_x}), c_x(x.c_x) { }
```

Further, a *move* constructor would look something like the following, with no new memory allocations but the `m_x` member in `x` set to `nullptr`. That instance of `X` can no longer modify the data `m_x` points to.

```
    X(X&& x) : m_x(x.m_x) : c_x(x.c_x) {
        x.m_x = nullptr;
    }
```